# Define common functions in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection

For define Util(common functions) we can use 3 approach :

**First :**

We can define a `File` and add `function` to it like this :

```
fun func1(): String {
    return "x"
}

fun func2(): String {
    return "y"
}
```

Then we can use this in every where like this :

```
fileName.func1()
```

**Second :**

We can define a `class` and add these `functions` to `class` like this :

```
class Util{
fun func1(): String {
    return "x"
}

fun func2(): String {
    return "y"
}
}
```

we can `inject` it and use this like :

```
 private val mUtil: Util by inject()

mutil.func1()
```

**Third:**

We can define an `object` like this :

```
object Util{
fun func1(): String {
    return "x"
}

fun func2(): String {
    return "y"
}
```

Then we can use this like :

```
Util.func1()
```

***suppose that we have reusable `fun` that it use in different `class` , `activity` or `fragment` now is better to use first , second or third ?***

Comment: "Which approach is better?"  Which is better: a hammer or a screwdriver?  You use them in different situations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman , Our situation is completely clear , we have reusable `fun` that it use in different `class` , `activity` or `fragment` now is better to use first , second or third ? by the other way i edit my question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman , Please explain a little about situations and utils like (hammer or screwdriver :) ) or answer this , when we have first approach in what situation we should use second or third?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding :

- In the first example, we simply define a function to be used within the scope of component (could be a fragment or an activity ..)
- In the second example, which I think more used in Java than Kotlin, you simply create a class in which you define some static variable or function to be accessed in your components later
- Example 3, I have no idea as I never used that

Comment: The first example, I think the OP means to be a top-level function that is not part of a class or object. The second example requires an instance before you can use the functions, so it's highly impractical for utility functions in both Java and Kotlin. There is no fourth example.

Comment: Do you mean it is not practical to reference consts from an object class in kotlin for example ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 , Thanks for your comment , why do you think that second is highly impractical and what do you think about third?

Comment: A utility function implies that the function doesn’t have to handle state, which is what a class instance is for. It would be nonsensical to require the class with no state to be instantiated every time you need to call a function like this.   Option 3 is a way you can organize your utility functions by putting them in a singleton object so you access by the name of the object. The difference between the two is that objects don’t require you to handle instances so there is no object being instantiated every time you use the utility functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation mate , appreciated

Answer (score 0):

first one is static function

second one is normal function

third is singleton function

you can decomplie to see the java code and see their differs.

`Kotlin file`

```
fun fun1() {}

class TestClass {

    fun testFun() {}
}

object ObjectClass {

    fun objectFun() {}
}
```

`Java file`

```
public final class TTTKt {
   public static final void fun1() {
   }
}

public final class TestClass {
   public final void testFun() {
   }
}

public final class ObjectClass {
   public static final ObjectClass INSTANCE;

   public final void objectFun() {
   }

   private ObjectClass() {
   }

   static {
      ObjectClass var0 = new ObjectClass();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i now `class` , `static` , `singletone` or `object` but my question is suppose that we have reusable `fun` that it use in different `class` , `activity` or `fragment` now is better to use first , second or third ?